# What does getBean() method do here?

Tags: java, spring, getter

What is the `getBean()` method doing here and how does it work in a program?

```
ApplicationContext aplicntxt = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml");  

Hello h = (Hello) aplicntxt.getBean("springconfig.xml");  
h.display();

Hello h2 = new Hello();  //if I write this
h2.display();
```

My question is why `h2.display` retrieves null value and `h.display` retrieves the stored values through springconfig.xml?

Please tell me what does

```
ApplicationContext aplicntxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml");
```

do first?

Are all the values of xml file stored to the pojo class setters at first step?

Then we are storing the values to an object `h`
by doing

```
Hello h = (Hello) aplicntxt.getBean("springconfig.xml");
```

Comment: All you need is just start to learn spring http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/

Comment: I want to know the internal flow, that isnt provided anywhere...i want to know what exactly is happening here step by step..
There are just two lines of code....please tell me the flow....Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [From spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

The interface `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` represents the `Spring IoC` container and is responsible for instantiating, configuring, and assembling the aforementioned beans. The container gets its instructions on what objects to instantiate, configure, and assemble by reading configuration metadata. The configuration metadata is represented in `XML, Java annotations, or Java code.` It allows you to express the objects that compose your application and the rich interdependencies between such objects.

Several implementations of the `ApplicationContext interface` are supplied out-of-the-box with Spring. In standalone applications it is common to create an instance of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.` While XML has been the traditional format for defining configuration metadata you can instruct the container to use Java annotations or code as the metadata format by providing a small amount of XML configuration to `declaratively` enable support for these additional metadata formats.

Now Your Question and its simple `ApplicationContext` activates the object(it is eager container) and looks for the `beans` declared so the objects are loaded whenever it is called.

Now consider if you have two beans , and you need one of them you will find that bean by using `ctx.getBean("beanId")` to load instance and to provide data declared with this bean where `beanId` will tell which object to `load`.

consider following example

`<bean id="a" class="package.Hello" /> 
 //here it will look for bean name and then loads the class`

Now when You call it like

```
ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXMLApplicationContext("configuration.xml");

//will look for configuration.xml bean file if it is not in path then throw execption.
```

now

```
Hello hello=ctx.getBean("a");

// if configuration.xml contains any bean named "a" and holds reference to class(hello) load it immediately and return object of that class
```

is same as

```
Hello hello=new Hello();
hello.method();
```

and it is creating object of `Hello` class by using `xml`

Comment: Okay. so object is loaded, now when i call "h.display()", is it accessing the xml file or invoking the method of just Hello Class?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is essentially "How does spring work", this is covered extensively by the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

The following creates all the beans defined by the springconfig.xml, that is it creates objects of the given types, and injects any properties you've defined, depending on your exact configuration it may also do things like package scanning, annotation processing etc.

```
ApplicationContext aplicntxt= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml");
```

XML

```
<bean class="org.example.Hello" id="foo" />
<bean class="org.example.Hello" id="bar" />
```

This would create an objects of type Hello and tag them with the IDs "foo" and "bar"

All the beans are stored against their IDs for later retrieval via getBean(), note this takes the bean ID or name, not the XML file.

```
Hello h = (Hello) aplicntxt.getBean("foo");
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, so what is the exact meaning of 'getting a bean'?
Are all the values already stored in Hello class and then we are retrieving them by 'h.display()'?

Comment: Getting a bean => Looking up a bean, by its ID from a registry, map, in-memory story, call it what you want. It's probably a HashMap under the hood..

Comment: I have a question here, if my Hello Class implements ApplicationContextAware, BeanNameAware and i have implemented methods within that class and if i put sysout in both respective methods for eg.
`public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
  System.out.println("Inside Application Context..."); }` and
`public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
  System.out.println("Inside Bean Name Aware, Bean Name is : " + beanName);
 }`
if i do `Hello h = (Hello) aplicntxt.getBean("foo");`
then it is printing Sysout two times for both foo and bar.

Comment: I can see output like 
`Inside Bean Name Aware, Bean Name is : foo
Inside Application Context...
Inside Bean Name Aware, Bean Name is : bar
Inside Application Context...`
Even though i have other beans in my spring.xml of different class it is not printing for those.

why exactly this is happening...?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing in code is called `Spring Dependency Injection` which let you define application beans and inject them when you need. like `getBean()` method that you use in your code which inject specific bean from XML file.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at this quickly, it appears that this code uses spring to initialize the Hello object with the values specified in the spring bean found in the xml file (I'm assuming that's what's in the filr, but I could be more specific if you post it).. When you create a second hello object you are using the constructor's default value for display, which is null.